# file stored in spring-mvc bean

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

I would need some help.

I am using spring-mvc with annotations, I have defined for the jsp BillBean:

```
public class BillBean {

private String address;
.......
private Annex annex;
}

 public class Annex {
 private String name:
 .........
 private Doc doc;
}

 public class Doc{
 private String name;
 .........
 private byte[] file;
}
```

I need to save a file in the Doc class, in the jsp I put the following code:

```
<form:input  type="file" path="annex.doc.file"  />
```

But after doing the submit, when attempting to validate the bean to validate class, I find that doc = null.

I understand that the problem is that doc has not been initialized by the handle spring beans, I tried creating a new instance in the constructor of BillBean but I failed to initialize the classe doc.

Anyone know tell me what I need to do to fix this problem?.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You have implemented the getter and setters for private fields right?

Comment: Does you form support `multipart/form-data` if not then add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form definition.

Comment: yes, i have implemented getters and setters and my form has defined enctype="multipart/form-data".the rest of my form fields are stored correctly. if i put the doc class on billBean, the file stored correctly,but now not initializes the class doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the problem was that I was returning a cloned instance of the doc class.

Spring set doc on clone instance and this instand don´t use never.

thanks for your help.